# Are embedding in GPT models trainable model parameters?

Tags: word-embeddings, llm, gpt

I have tried to search from a few sources, but I did not see any one of them specifically talking about this issue. For example [This blog post](https://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/) seems to imply that the embedding used in transformer is learned separately (in other words fixed during transformer training.

> As is the case in NLP applications in general, we begin by turning each input word into a vector using an embedding algorithm.

but it is rather vague. But in [nano GPT code](https://github.com/karpathy/nanoGPT/blob/master/model.py) it seems embedding layer is part of the model, which means it will be updated during the model training. So which case is it? Is the embedding for GPT a pre-processing stage or part of the trainable parameters?

Comment: I don't see where in the blog post that what you describe is implied; it would help to _edit_ the question to include a quote so that we can clarify it.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy done. and there is a link from that statement which tells you what 'algorithm' it is referring to. The fact that it is a separate algorithm heavily implies it is a pre-processing procedure.

Comment: Thanks for selecting the quote. The quote doesn't actually entail that it's pre-processing. (Admittedly, the embedding "algorithm" isn't terribly sophisticated. A lookup table of word to index, then slicing out a row in a matrix.) So I wouldn't stress about it. GPT embeddings are learnable parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking for GPT1-3, the models learn an embedding. These models follow the paper [Attention Is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf) which states that they "use learned embeddings to convert the input tokens and output tokens to vectors of dimension d_model".

Skim the papers for GPT 1,2 and 3 to see that GPT3 follows GPT2, GPT2 follows GPT and GPT uses the architecture from [Attention Is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf). Looking at the [code for gpt2](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/gpt2/modeling_gpt2.py) may also help you understand what is going on under the hood.

Comment: yeap. I referred to the nanoGPT paper and saw the embedding layer is trainable. But if you look at the specific blog post I mentioned it seems to suggest otherwise. I am trying to reconcile this two conflicting sources of information.